# Can't attach VHD

Tags: windows-7, backup, data-recovery, windows-backup, vhd

I think I may be experiencing that horrible moment when the backup fails. Somewhere hiding on this VHD is an SQL database I need to extract. This is from a Windows backup, not a virtual machine. I'm totally stumped. What can I do with a vhd I can't even mount anywhere?

`Diskpart has referenced an object which is not up-to-date`

`The operation failed to complete because the Disk Management console view is not up-to-date.`

`WinImage: Error reading file`

The other VHDs from different partitions load up fine...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not the correct or proper solution, but it will get you your SQL database.

Download [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) and after installing it, open the vhd using it, you will be able to extract any file you want from the vhd then.

Comment: It may not be correct or proper, but it is awesome. Worked like an absolute charm. Looks like there was very little file corruption even. It's interesting that I didn't run across this solution at TechNet or anywhere else.