# Why can't I open a VHD file?

Tags: windows-7, backup, vhd

I am trying to access some individual files from a Windows 7 backup created by means of the built-in *Save and Restore* functionality, from within Windows 7.

The backup data is stored in `.vhd` files, in particular a 160 GB file. I can attach it in disk management as described [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-restore-vhd-file-backup/f3ed3ca5-3079-40cd-a959-835caeba80a7).

The disk is shown as an NTFS volume and mounted to a drive letter, but there is no preview on the occupied/empty disk size. When I try to open the drive in Windows Explorer, I am just getting the error message *Access Denied*.

I have tried opening the `.vhd` file with 7zip as described [in another question](https://superuser.com/questions/454145/cant-attach-vhd), but 7zip claims there is nothing in there except for a file named `disallowedcert.stl` of some 10 MB.

Furthermore, it does not seem to be a permission problem, as suggested [in another forum thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Windows/en-US/086cf3b9-f6cc-417b-9685-62b33ee5cc29/access-denied-on-vhd-permissions?forum=winserverhyperv). The `.vhd` file belongs to the current user of the computer and there are no access restrictions to them or the local administrators, as far as I can tell from the file properties.

**What is going on and how can I open that .vhd file?**

Comment: Sounds like you don’t have the permissions to view or even list the contents of the root directory of the drive.  Ownership of the file isn’t a concern, even with read access, mounting would be possible.  Please be kind when responding to this comment....

Comment: @Ramhound: How do I change (or even just confirm) that?

Comment: No suggestions on that front; Windows 10 has native mounting capabilities of vhd files

Comment: @Ramhound: So has Windows 7, it would seem (via disk management). Or are there any restrictions to that? I'll try getting that file onto a Win10 machine, though.

Comment: When mounted can diskpart (command line utility) see the partitions?

Comment: @Ramhound: diskpart shows a partition in the mounted `.vhd` file.

Comment: @Ramhound: Wait, what error? diskpart doesn't show an error, it just shows that there is a large partition on the mounted drive. Yet, I seem to remain unable to look into that partition e.g. with Windows Explorer.

Comment: I could have sworn your comment indicated there was an error.